# Delegation the Tezos to the staking team through Trust wallet. I have following question. Please help

Tags: delegation

On 6th of June, I delegated 2.1 Tezos throug my personal wallet which is Trust Wallet. After that it showed Delgated -2.1. On 27th June 2020 I bought 122 units of Tezos and transferred it to my XTZ wallet in Trust wallet. And it shows Available 124.xx and staked 124.xx i.e. fully staked. However, to note that when I first staked 2.1 units of Tezos it showed -2.1 delegated, but those 122 units which I bought is recorded as received but not -122 like previous one, it still shows fully staked i.e. Available 124 and staked 124.
I have two questions

1. Are all my XTZ staked or do I have to unstake and restake them?
2. Its been more than 45 days and I have not yet received single staking reward. When will I receive rewards?
   I staked to staking team.

Answer (score 2):

1. All your XTZ are staked within a single address. So, if you stake 100 then transfer in another 200, all 300 will automatically stake. However, each new addition to your wallet must go through the standard waiting period.
2. Check your rewards by using https://baking-bad.org/ This will show you when your rewards are expected. Otherwise, contact your baker directly.